# Linux: What could be the best option for making asynchronous timer to trigger IPC?

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, timer

I am developing a system where a single parent process creates 10 child processes.  The parent process assigns independent tasks to individual child and parent-child communication is done via message queues. Now I need to add one more functionality by which asynchronous timers would run and at a regular interval, timer asks the parent process to ping each child process to check if child is running fine and child replies back. If a child does not reply back thrice after the ping call is made, the parent kills the child and forks another child to assign that task. What would be the best option to add this timer which would trigger IPC between parent and child processes at a regular interval? I was trying to build individual process wise timer with [timer_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) but could not achieve it.

Comment: I think what you try to implement is a "watchdog" for the child processes. The question is what is the best concept to achieve this. Do you have real time requirements for this watchdog? If not, another way might be to let the children send a signal to the parent process that they are still alive. The parent process could look when the children processes signals and kill the child process if the last signal is too long ago.

Comment: @gmug the 'watchdog' term is quite appropriate. I need a real time one. Parent should keep on doing its own job while timers will ask parent to ping children at a regular interval.